# How do I get all of the latest "versions" from my table with one MySQL query?

Tags: mysql

I have a table with the following basic structure.

```
unique_id | name | original | version
-----------------
1 | a1 | 1 | 1

2 | b1 | 2 | 1

3 | a2 | 1 | 2

4 | a3 | 1 | 3

5 | c1 | 5 | 1

6 | b2 | 2 | 2
```

Now it should be obvious from this that there is a form of version control, where we keep track of the original document, and also track the version of the current document.

If I want to get the latest version of a particular document I do something like the following.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE original = (SELECT original FROM table WHERE id = 3) ORDER BY version DESC
```

My question is, how do I do get a list of all of the most recent versions in the table with only one query?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find row with maximum value of id in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1305473/find-row-with-maximum-value-of-id-in-mysql)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea is to

- build a list of all original ID's with the current maximum version
- join your table with this list of unique identifiers.

> ```
> SELECT *
> FROM table t
>      INNER JOIN (     
>        SELECT original, MAX(version) as version
>        FROM tabel
>        GROUP BY original
>      ) tmax ON tmax.original = t.original and tmax.version = t.version
> ```

Comment: That will work, but it involves a corrolated subquery, which has performance implications.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1305473/mysql-query-question/1305642#1305642 for a more optimal approach.

Comment: This is not a corrolated subquery.

Comment: as a side not, the OP should measure each solution's performance and draw his conclusions from that. I doubt you'll find a more optimal solution than the INNER JOIN scenario.

Comment: Sorry, you're right; misread it. It does create a temp table, though, which the other solution avoids. Curiously, MySQL 5.1.30 doesn't like the syntax; think it must be a bug. Ran into this in the other q, too. "Unknown column 'tmax.version' in 'on clause'" You can work around it, though, using `AS`: `SELECT t.original, t.version FROM yourTableName t INNER JOIN (SELECT original, MAX(version) AS vmax FROM yourTableName GROUP BY original) tmax ON tmax.original = t.original and tmax.vmax = t.version;`

Comment: Thank you. I've adjusted the answer to take care of the syntax issue. Now all we need to resolve is the performance issue <g>.

Comment: Create a composite index on `(original, version)` to get rid on temptable.

Comment: @Quassnoi: what took you so long? ;)

Comment: Might have missed this question when it was just asked :)